# Select a specific ul nested inside an id

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS script inside my HTML file. I want to target a specific UL which is nested inside a *div* with a container class and then a *div* with ID.  Below is the code. I am not able to remove bullets from *li* so that a menu can be prepared.

Below is the code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

#topbanner {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#hod {
  float: left;
}

div#hod ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: red;
  margin: 0px padding: 0px;
}

div#hod ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="topbanner">
    <div id="hod">
      <p>This is a test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="topmenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your `div#hod ul` does not have a `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```css
#topmenu ul li {
   list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61556887/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).